# Как изменить вывод 'page-attributes' в метабоксе?

Tags: wordpress

Ситуация такова:
В файл functions.php зарегистрировал постайп. 
functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_post_type');
function add_my_post_type() {
register_post_type('my_post_type', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'               => 'my_post_type', // основное название для типа записи
        'singular_name'      => 'my_post_type (one)', // название для одной записи этого типа
        'add_new'            => 'Добавить my_post_type', // для добавления новой записи
        'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление my_post_type', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
        'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование my_post_type',
        'parent_item_colon'  => '55555my_post_type', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
        'menu_name'          => 'my_post_type', // название меню
    ),
    'description'         => '',
    'public'              => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // по умолчанию значение show_in_menu
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => null,
    'show_in_rest'        => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
    'rest_base'           => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
    'menu_position'       => null,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-products',
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'supports'            => array('title','editor','page-attributes'// !!!!!),
    'taxonomies'          => array(),
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'rewrite'             => true,
    'query_var'           => true,

));
}
```

Добавился постайп my_post_type и в сайдбаре справа выводится метабокс "Свойства страницы", в 'supports' поставил так же чтоб выводило 'page-attributes' (данный параметр выводит родительский элемент и порядок). Обновил версию wordpress c 4.9.2 до версии 4.9.3 и параметр 'page-attributes' стал выводить только порядок БЕЗ выбора родительского элемента. Как сделать, чтоб параметр 'page-attributes' выводил выбор родительского элемента как в версии 4.9.2?

Comment: Только что Ваш код использовал. Всё нормально. Когда 1 опубликованная страница, соответственно списка нет. А когда создаёшь 2 страницу, то уже есть. Правда я на WordPress 4.9.4 пробовал.

Comment: @campusboy, спасибо,  ща попробую

Comment: @campusboy, обновил - всё стало на свои места. Напишите ответ, я Вам его засчитаю, как верный

Comment: Спасибо за доброту, Александр! Не считаю этот ответ реальным, просто совет, заметка :-) Отлично, что всё получилось!